# How to format a directed acyclic graph into lists of lists

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a list of edges that connect nodes together and need to output this in the format shown below. There are no cycles and no cases where a node needs to be in two lists.

I've been trying to find an algorithm for this but the Topological Sorting algorithms that I found only output the order of the nodes, not the grouping of them like I need.

I've had little success so far due to the difficulty of finding where to close the brackets when starting at the first node or where to open them when starting at the last node. Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

**Edit:**
This is how the data is stored in VB.NET:

```
Public Class Box
    Public id as Integer
End Class

Public Class Edge
    Public box1 As Box
    Public box2 As Box
End Class

Public edges As List(Of Edge)
```

And the desired output is to a text file in the format below. The idea is that branches are wrapped in "Parallel" tags and sequential steps are wrapped in "Series" tags. The number of branches is arbitrary but there will not be a case where a node needs to be in two places at once in the lists (for example, node 3 is guaranteed not to connect to node 6 because they are in different lineages)

```
Series
[
    Node 1
    Parallel
    [
        Series
        [
            Node 2
            Parallel
            [
                Series
                [
                    Node 5
                    Node 8
                ]
                Series
                [
                    Node 6
                ]
            ]
        ]
        Series
        [
            Parallel
            [
                Series
                [
                    Node 3
                ]
                Series
                [
                    Node 4
                ]
            ]
            Node 7
        ]
    ]
    Node 9
    Node 10
]
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include the desired output as code - not as an image. It would also help to explain how the DAG is represented as a data structure, ideally with code too.

Comment: @kaya3 Thanks for the feedback, I made to requested edits. Hopefully this will be easier to follow

Comment: At each node we can calculate the difference between inwards and outwards degree of a node.
If the difference in the in-out degree is == 0 then that node will be series node else it will be parallel node.

Answer (score 0):

Because of your edit, I think you are looking for a decomposition of a series-parallel graph. According to Wikipedia, this is possible in linear time. Please see Wikipedia for more information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series-parallel_graph

Note that series-parallel graphs require a specific structure, e.g. they need a *source* node (in your example node 1) and a *sink* node (in your example node 10). If your graphs don't have such a structure in general, please provide some more details about your graphs and your problem.